Boy reading a comic book hidden in a Bible
I'm looking for a movie of unknown origin which I watched with a Hungarian dubbing. I've seen it 5-6 years ago and only the beginning. John Travolta might have been in it.
It starts in either a religious school or a temple where a young boy is reading a comic book hidden in his Bible. The priest soon notices this and beats him up. The boy had a little girlfriend whom he was forbidden to socialize with. One time, they were discovered and the girl fell from the stairs (?) and died.
The film fast forwards years after this, and we see the boy grown up, stepping out of his home, fixing something on his door that will serve as an indicator to him if somebody has opened it in his absence.

It's The Saint (1997) with Val Kilmer and Elisabeth Shue.

At the Saint Ignatius Orphanage, a rebellious boy named John Rossi refers to himself as "Simon Templar" and leads a group of fellow orphans as they attempt to run away to escape their harsh treatment. When Simon is caught by the head priest, he witnesses the tragic death of a girl he had taken a liking to when she accidentally falls from a balcony. (Wikipedia)







Wonderful! Thank you so much! How did you find it?
